# How to find max value from alphanumeric string on the basis of numeric value in db2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am working on db2 database.I want to get max value from a column.That column is of varchar type and has alphanumeric values such as

> abc100
>   , abc101
>   ,abc102......
>   I want to get 'abc102' as a result.
>   Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the range of the numbers? Is the text part identical for all rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `max()`:

```
select max(col)
from t;
```

Your data is such that the alphabetical maximum is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually I have data in my column like this-- abc1,abc2,..,abc50,pqr1,pqr2,...,pqr120,xyz1,xyz2,...,xyz200.Now i want to get max value for having prefix xyz.So for this purpose i used this query --select MAX(fieldName) from table  where fieldName like '%xyz%'-- this query was returning result as xyz99 as max but result should be xyz200 as max..Now i want to know how to use 'like' query in MAX function to get desired output.OR is there any way to find out max value on the basis pf its numeric value.

Comment: @AkshayTyagi . . . That is not the question that you asked.  You should ask *another* question.  If you modify this one, then that may draw downvotes to this answer, which is rude.